# Gradle install not valid

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

im trying to build a android game in unity 2021.3.6f1 and when i try to make the build an error shows up:

Exception: Gradle install not valid
Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle..ctor (System.String gradleLauncherPath, System.Int32 jvmHeapSize) (at <0c48b869e61f4b36ab26a0a29a41593a>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.CreateGradleInstance () (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.ExecuteWarmup (System.String stagingArea) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)

what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have problems with your Gradle installation/path.

Have you tried the answers in this thread?: [Unity error: Exception: Gradle install not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59278427/unity-error-exception-gradle-install-not-valid)

> In the Editor > Preferences > External Tools tab, there is a check box
> for Gradle Install with Unity. Make sure this check box is checked